# Downgrade from Evolution 3.16 to Evolution 3.12

Tags: apt, gnome, package-management, email, evolution

I am using Ubuntu 15.04. I installed Gnome Evolution 3.16 by adding the Gnome PPA in my sources list. This worked briefly, but then Evolution stopped working with my Google Apps accounts (happened on two separate fresh installs, and worked fine initially, but stopped working after I restarted Evolution).

I have since removed Evolution 3.16 (used the Software center to uninstall), and also removed the PPA for Gnome from my sources. I have rebuilt the sources list (apt-get update... and done an autoclean and autoremove as well).

I am getting a number of dependencies unmet errors when I try and install the default Ubuntu tested version of Evolution (ver 3.12) now:

> *Depends: evolution-common(=3.12.11-0ubuntu3) but 3.12.11-0ubuntu3 is to be installed*

Running the install from the terminal results in the following error (using *sudo apt-get install evolution*):

> *Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.*
>
> *The following information may help to resolve the situation:*
>
> *The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    evolution : Depends: evolution-data-server (< 3.13) but 3.16.0-fta1 is to be installed*
>
> *Recommends: evolution-plugins but it is not going to be installed*
>
> *Recommends: spamassassin but it is not going to be installed or bogofilter but it is not going to be installed*
>
> *E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just remove the package with `sudo apt-get purge evolution-common`

Comment: That didn't work - says 'evolution-common' is not installed.

Comment: it seems ppa sources are still there so you need to use ppa-purge (see my answer). 
what does `sudo apt-get install -f` give?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add the PPAs again, and yes, I'am sure.
2. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`
3. `sudo apt-get install -f`
4. `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
5. Use `sudo ppa-purge <the_ppa>`to remove the PPAs and to downgrade your GNOME environment

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the ppa and purge it out

`sudo apt-add repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

Then Update the system

`sudo apt-get update`

then purge it off

`ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3`

You can try `sudo apt-get install -f` to try fixing stuffs

Comment: great it worked. Care to upvote?  ;)

Comment: don't have enough rep. points... couldn't even attach images till I get to a rep of 10. Hence to comment above about this solution working.

Comment: don't worry! its okay!